# python selenium identificate browser running

Tags: python, selenium

In my website when users execute one operation in server start new seesion chrome webdrive (python selenium), for monitorization need identificate the browser opened.

```
UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.{NNR} (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2288.6 Safari/537.{NNR}".format(NNR=NNR)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-agent={UA}'.format(UA=UA))
options.add_argument("--lang=it");
options.add_argument("--test-type")
self.driver   = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

need same solution, when the browser is opened want to be associated with a name, visible to the human eye! How i can gived name to browser in selenium ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for... idntify the browser type (chrome, firefox, etc) or some other browser identifier?

Comment: yeap, unclear question) you need some int variable that will increase by 1 each time browser session starts?